# Text Formula - need to remove ".00" from result

Tags: formula

Here is the formula I am using:

```
"$" & IF( 
  Lease_PB_Total_Price__c >= 1000000, 
  TEXT(FLOOR( Lease_PB_Total_Price__c  / 1000000)) & ",", 
  "") & 
IF( 
  Lease_PB_Total_Price__c >= 1000, 
  RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Lease_PB_Total_Price__c / 1000)), 3) & ",", 
  "") &
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Lease_PB_Total_Price__c)), 3) & "." &

IF( 
  MOD(Lease_PB_Total_Price__c , 1) * 100 < 10, 
  "0" & TEXT(ROUND(MOD(Lease_PB_Total_Price__c , 1), 2) * 100), 
  TEXT(MIN(ROUND(MOD(Lease_PB_Total_Price__c , 1), 2) * 100, 99)) 
)
```

Here is the result:

$30,628.00

I want to lose the ".00"

I tried rounding but do not think I can round with text?

Please help and thanks!

​Shannon

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your formula is of type "Number". If so, edit your formula, under "Formula Options", choose "0" in the "Decimal Numbers" picklist.

That should do it!

Comment: Nope. Text field

Comment: Can this be changed to a numeric, or even better, currency formula?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
"$" & IF( 
  Lease_PB_Total_Price__c >= 1000000, 
  TEXT(FLOOR( Lease_PB_Total_Price__c  / 1000000)) & ",", 
  "") & 
IF( 
  Lease_PB_Total_Price__c >= 1000, 
  RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Lease_PB_Total_Price__c / 1000)), 3) & ",", 
  "") &
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Lease_PB_Total_Price__c)), 3)
```

You could use `RIGHT(TEXT(ROUND(Lease_PB_Total_Price__c,0)), 3)` to round cents 49c or less => $0, 50c and more => $1