# How to use a formula field to display both image and currency?

Tags: formula-field

I am attempting to display dollar amounts with an icon next to them in order to indicate if they are over/below a certain dollar amount.

So far the closest I can come to accomplishing this is a formula such as :

```
IF(currencyfield__c < currencyfield2__c,

Text(currencyfield__c) & IMAGE('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015550000000fff, Name) , 

Text(currencyfield__c))
```

But unfortunately since this will display the currencyfield__c as text no commas will appear in the currency to properly display thousands.

And apparently I can't solve this by making the formula field a currency field because then it won't properly display the image.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can't you have two fields, one for the image and other for the number, for this? I'm not sure you can have both at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately it can't be two fields. I need to be able to display the dollar amount and icon in one field so I can include it in reports and views. If I try to display it as two separate fields it's very confusing because they don't appear next to one another very well.

Comment: I just realized I was using the word "columns" when I meant to say "commas". I'm sorry for the confusion. 

The currency fields don't display properly when using the TEXT() function because there are no commas.

Answer (score 4):

```
IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01536000001fC4X", "US") + " US - Price: " +  TEXT(Value__c)
```

This gives me this result in my test organization:

[image: screenshot]

So you can do what you asked in your question, but if you work with more than one currency, then you will need to have an IF next to the `IMAGE` tag to set the proper currency prefix.

Note: My locale is set to Brazil, and that's why it is displaying R$ as the currency, instead of $.

Comment: Using TEXT(field__c) will not properly display commas for the currency field value. Maybe I'm missing something in your example ?

Comment: No, you are right. The text function converts the value to a plain decimal, just adding the dot to sign the decimal cases. You actually might need to create a text field, and populate it with the formatted number. This can be achieved with a trigger on the object, that recalculates this when the record is inserted or updated. Sorry, I didn't notice it earlier because I used a small number.

Comment: @Zoom_v This is possible with a more complex formula, [check it out here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118032/text-formula-need-to-remove-00-from-result/118049#118049)

Comment: Then you've got it! You will need a trigger only if the formula gets too big to get compiled. :)